# In php validation when wrong data is found the page get refreshed and the data's already entered will became empty.How to prevent the loss?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am a very beginner in php.I tried a form validation in php while validating my form.when wrong data is found the browser will show an alert box, when i click it the browser reloads the page and the details already entered in the form get refreshed and i need to enter it from the first.
How to avoid the page refresh while validating.
sorry for my poor english
Thank you in advance

This is my php form coding
formvalidate.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>USER REGISTRATION</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  name="registrationform" id="formid"   method="get";>
name:<input type="text" id="n1" name="name">  <br><br>
username:<input type="text" id="u1" name="username"> <br><br>
password:<input type="password" id="p1" name="password"> <br><br>
confirm password:<input type="password" id="p2" name="password2"> <br><br>
Address   :<textarea name="address" id= "a1"rows="4" cols="40"> </textarea><br><br>
phone   :<input id="ph" type="numbers" name="phone" ><br><br>
<input  type="submit" name="register"  value="register" >
<a href="login.php"><input id="button"  type="button"  value="cancel"> </a>
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="userlogin";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if(!$conn)
    {
    die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ?>
<?php   


    if (isset($_GET['register'])) {
    if(empty($_GET['name']))
    {
        echo'name should not empty';
            }

    if ( empty($_GET['username'])) {
    echo 'user name should not be empty';

    } else {
        $name1=$_GET['name'];
        $uname=$_GET['username'];

    $sql = "select * from contact where username='$uname'";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result->num_rows==1)
    {
        echo"username already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"username available";
    }
    return false;
    }

    if((empty($_GET['password']))||(empty($_GET['confirmpassword'])))
    {
    echo'password and confirm password should not be empty';
    return false;
    }
    else{
    $pwd=$_GET['password'];
    $cpwd=$_GET['confirmpassword'];
    if($pwd.length==6){
    echo'password should not lesser than 6';
    }
    else
    {
    if($pwd==$cpwd){
    echo'password accepted';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'password does not matched';
    return false;
    }
    }
    }

    if(empty($_GET['address']))
    {
    echo'address should not be empty';
    return false;
    }

    if(empty($_GET['phone']))
    {
    echo'phone should not be empty';
    return false;
    }
    }
?>
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33680710/5073447

Comment: You have several options to do that. Anyway, my recommendation is that you should use an external php file to handle the data (through direct post or AJAX). And if the data contains passwords or sensible data, do not use GET method. Also your code seems SQL injectable, you must sanitize the data before send it to the database (or better: use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).

Comment: Use javascript validation

Comment: also i  need to check user name availability for that i need to enter the database and should check weather  the user name is available or not..This can be done in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform the check at the start of page, something like;

```
$sParam1 = "";

if (isset ($_GET['param1']) ){
 $sParam1 = (string)$_GET['param1'];
}
```

Leave the form at the bottom of the page and echo the variables in the `value` param;

```
<form method="get">
   <input type="text" name="param1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sParam1); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: you can also create a veriable to hold error say `$sError`. Everytime you find an error, missing field, incorrect type etc, append to the string. Say that param1 is an int and should be a string, do. `$sError .= "[Param1Int]";`

Comment: If you found my question is worth please upvote my post

Comment: no problem at all, great to hear its working! 
The sError var can be quite useful too, not just for preventing some parts of code running. You can use it to add an error class. Say you delimit the string as such; `[param1NoContent][param2NotInt]`, you can check/access in the html/class attribude as such;
`class="<?php if($sError !== ""){if(strpos($sError, '[Param1]') !== false){echo "has-error";}}?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can also set something like

if(isset($_GET['name'] ){echo "value=$_GET[name]";}

for each of the input attributes.

Though i believe you should use POST attribute in form rather tham GET.

Also, you have not set the 'action' attribute for the form !

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but  am performing validation in the same page..so only i've used GET

Comment: You can perform validation in the same page by setting <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">